# SQL Query to fetch parent record based on multiple conditions on child record

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have two table Parent P and Child C

**Parent**

```
Id Name
1   AAA
2   BBB
3   CCC
```

**Child**

```
Id ParId Name Value
11 1     XXX    1
12 1     YYY    7
19 1     ZZZ    9
13 2     XXX    1
14 2     YYY    2
20 1     ZZZ    7
15 3     XXX    1
16 3     YYY    2
18 3     ZZZ    8
```

I want to fetch the parent records for which XXX value is 1 and YYY is not 2 or zzz value is not 7.
In this case, I should get 1 and 3 as result. Please suggest.

Comment: for parId = 3, YYY is 2, so how come it should be included in result? Please give the expected resultset also.

Comment: What about if there is XXX with value 1 but no YYY and/or ZZZ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules can be checked in the `HAVING` section of a query with a `CASE` statement.

If all the name have to be checked, i.e. if the child don't have all the three names it should not be in the resulset, the check for three rules is static

```
SELECT c.ParId, p.Name
FROM   Child c
       INNER JOIN Parent p ON c.ParID = p.Id
GROUP BY c.ParId, p.Name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN c.Name = 'XXX' AND c.Value = 1 Then 1
                WHEN c.Name = 'YYY' AND c.Value <> 2 Then 1
                WHEN c.Name = 'ZZZ' AND c.Value <> 7 Then 1
                ELSE 0
           END) = 3;
```

If only the name that are in the data have to be checked, i.e. if the child have only 'XXX' and it's value is 1 then it's parent should be in the resulset, the check is dynamic

```
SELECT c.ParId, p.Name
FROM   Child c
       INNER JOIN Parent p ON c.ParID = p.Id
WHERE  c.NAME IN ('XXX', 'YYY', 'ZZZ')
GROUP BY c.ParId, p.Name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN c.Name = 'XXX' AND c.Value = 1 Then 1
                WHEN c.Name = 'YYY' AND c.Value <> 2 Then 1
                WHEN c.Name = 'ZZZ' AND c.Value <> 7 Then 1
                ELSE 0
           END) = COUNT(DISTINCT c.NAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct p.id 
from parent p 
join child c 
    on p.id=c.parid 
where (c.name='XXX' and c.value = 1) or (c.name='YYY' and c.value = 2) or ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from parent p where 
    not exists(select * from child c where p.id  = c.parid and (c.xxx = 1))
    and not exists(select * from child c where p.id  = c.parid and (c.yyy = 2))
    and not exists(select * from child c where p.id  = c.parid and (c.zzz = 7))
```